# Is there a finite geometric series variant for these functions of k?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

The geometric series can be solve efficiently with

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^k = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r}$

Is the a series or approximation for the more complex case:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^{k \sqrt{1 + bk^2}} = ?$

or for

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^{k^m} = ?$

r, n, b, m are constants

Edit 1:
If no exact solutions exists, I will be happy with an approximation that is quicker than direct summation.

$|r| < 1$ r is complex

m is real number between 1 and 2

b is a real number between 0 and 1

n is less than 1024

The exponent $f(k)$ does need to be $k \sqrt{1 + bk^2}$ or $k^m$ but ideally f should be monotonically increasing and $n < f(n) < \sqrt{2}n^2$ and f'(k) > 0, f"(k) > 0. Solution for such similar functions will be helpful, like maybe there is an exact solution exist for polynomials, I don't know.

I know one approximation is to linearize:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}r_0^{a_0 k} + \sum_{k=(n_0+1)}^{n_1}r_1^{a_1 k} + ... + \sum_{k=(n_{i-1})}^{n}r_i^{a_i k}$

and use the closed form of each term.

Linearizing creates a function f(k) that has the properties I am looking for except that f"(k) is not > 0 everywhere from k = 0 to 1024. Is there a another approximation?

Comment: Define "efficiently". Both your series can be approximated. Both can be given in terms of special functions. If you're asking for elementary expressions for either, no such formula are known and in my personal view I'd say likely do not exist.

Comment: In fact I think it could be possible to show no such rational expression exists for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^{k^m}$ when $|r|<1$ unless $m=1$ though I'm not really interested enough to dig deeper.

Comment: I mean approximation as something that is faster then solving summation directly by just adding the terms). I am interested in the $|r| < 1$ where $r$ is a complex number. I know one approximation is to linearize and do something like $\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}r_0^{a_0 k} + \sum_{k=(n_0+1)}^{n_1}r_1^{a_1 k} + ... + \sum_{k=(n_{i-1})}^{n}r_i^{a_i k}$ and use the closed form for each part. I am not really looking for accuracy. Also, if there are answers for other similar functions of k that are out there, that will be helpful.

Comment: Okay so we can assume $r\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|r|<1$. Can you be more precise about $n,b,m$? I assumed $m$ was a natural number, is this the case? What about $b$? Also when you say "solving" the summation, I'm going to assume you were referring to the approximation. Now anything can be an approximation of anything, so the question is how accurate you want your approximation to be.  For example does it just need to be asymptotic as $n\to \infty$? Do you need a bound on the error term?

Comment: In short #$1$ specify what values the constant can be, #$2$ specify how accurate you want your approximation.

Comment: The $\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^{k^m}$ can be a special case of Jacobi triple product. This can give you a new idea.